# How to stop element div (coming soon) from moving?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, responsive

I want to make a responsive Coming soon page [website](https://unripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com/)

and i added the coming soon script in this [site](https://icons8.com/cssload/en/spinners/3)

and this is the [script](https://jsfiddle.net/talabe/z39Lftew/) of loading/coming after i modify it

but the problem i have when i try to resize  website from down to up the the loading/coming soon will move up but i just want it to be under the logo always ? this the website script [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talabe/cs168tvL/2/).

```css
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}





#cssload-wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 15;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.cssload-loader {
 width: 225px;
 height: 225px;
 border: 2px rgb(245,131,32) solid;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 65%;
 margin: -113px 0 0 -113px;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-loading {
 font-size: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 21px;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: 30px;
 color: rgb(0,101,179);
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  -o-text-transform: uppercase;
  -ms-text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cssload-loader-circle-1 {
 width: 207px;
 height: 207px;
 left: 8px;
 top: 8px;
 border: 2px rgb(0,101,179) solid;
 position: absolute;
 border-right-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-loader-circle-2 {
 width: 189px;
 height: 189px;
 left: 8px;
 top: 8px;
 border: 2px transparent solid;
 position: absolute;
 border-right-color: rgb(245,131,32);
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line {
 width: 15px;
 height: 3px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
 position: absolute;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(1) {
 left: 24px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -2px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(2) {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(3) {
 top: 24px;
 left: 50%;
 width: 3px;
 height: 15px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(4) {
 transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
 right: 50px;
 top: 50px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(5) {
 right: 24px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -2px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(6) {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 right: 50px;
 bottom: 50px;
 background: rgb(245,131,32);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline {
 position: absolute;
 width: 5px;
 height: 3px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(7) {
 transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
 left: 32px;
 top: 75px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(8) {
 transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
 left: 75px;
 top: 32px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(9) {
 transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
 right: 75px;
 top: 32px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(10) {
 transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
 right: 32px;
 top: 75px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(11) {
 transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
 right: 30px;
 bottom: 74px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-needle {
 width: 21px;
 height: 21px;
 border: 2px rgb(0,101,179) solid;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-needle:before {
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5.5px 75px 5.5px 0;
 border-color: transparent rgb(245,131,32) transparent transparent;
 position: absolute;
 right: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -5.5px 0 0 0;
 border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}





@keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -o-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -o-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -o-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<center>
<img class='responsive' src='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VTCVnBuSn3I/XAxJCeM2HeI/AAAAAAAAAuw/vddRM_bPEgQwkXeFbQ5Uwgd5wlRDwpWPQCLcBGAs/s1600/600.PNG'/>
   </center>

<div id="cssload-wrapper">
 <div class="cssload-loader">
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-loader-circle-1"><div class="cssload-loader-circle-2"></div></div>
  <div class="cssload-needle"></div>
  <div class="cssload-loading">COMING SOON</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. I changed the position of the clock, and got rid of some margins.

```css
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.logo{
  width:60%;
  margin: auto;
}



#cssload-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cssload-loader {
 width: 225px;
 height: 225px;
 border: 2px rgb(245,131,32) solid;
 position: relative;
 /* left: 50%;
 top: 65%; */
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-loading {
 font-size: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 21px;
 font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 left: 0;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: 30px;
 color: rgb(0,101,179);
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
  -o-text-transform: uppercase;
  -ms-text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cssload-loader-circle-1 {
 width: 207px;
 height: 207px;
 left: 8px;
 top: 8px;
 border: 2px rgb(0,101,179) solid;
 position: absolute;
 border-right-color: transparent;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 3.45s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-loader-circle-2 {
 width: 189px;
 height: 189px;
 left: 8px;
 top: 8px;
 border: 2px transparent solid;
 position: absolute;
 border-right-color: rgb(245,131,32);
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 5.75s linear infinite;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line {
 width: 15px;
 height: 3px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
 position: absolute;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(1) {
 left: 24px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -2px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(2) {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(3) {
 top: 24px;
 left: 50%;
 width: 3px;
 height: 15px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(4) {
 transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
 right: 50px;
 top: 50px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(5) {
 right: 24px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -2px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-line:nth-child(6) {
 transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 right: 50px;
 bottom: 50px;
 background: rgb(245,131,32);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline {
 position: absolute;
 width: 5px;
 height: 3px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(7) {
 transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
 left: 32px;
 top: 75px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(8) {
 transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(67.5deg);
 left: 75px;
 top: 32px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(9) {
 transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(112.5deg);
 right: 75px;
 top: 32px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(10) {
 transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(157.5deg);
 right: 32px;
 top: 75px;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-subline:nth-child(11) {
 transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(22.5deg);
 right: 30px;
 bottom: 74px;
 background: rgb(0,101,179);
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-needle {
 width: 21px;
 height: 21px;
 border: 2px rgb(0,101,179) solid;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -12px 0 0 -12px;
 z-index: 1;
 border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: pegIt 3.45s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.cssload-loader .cssload-needle:before {
 content: "";
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5.5px 75px 5.5px 0;
 border-color: transparent rgb(245,131,32) transparent transparent;
 position: absolute;
 right: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -5.5px 0 0 0;
 border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0;
}





@keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -o-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -o-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -o-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -o-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes pegIt {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 16% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(75deg);
 }
 25% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(55deg);
 }
 30% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
 36% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(170deg);
 }
 42% {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
 }
 50% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(227deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
<img class='responsive' src='https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VTCVnBuSn3I/XAxJCeM2HeI/AAAAAAAAAuw/vddRM_bPEgQwkXeFbQ5Uwgd5wlRDwpWPQCLcBGAs/s1600/600.PNG'/>
   </div>

<div id="cssload-wrapper" align="center">
 <div class="cssload-loader">
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-line"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-subline"></div>
  <div class="cssload-loader-circle-1"><div class="cssload-loader-circle-2"></div></div>
  <div class="cssload-needle"></div>
  <div class="cssload-loading">COMING SOON</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And for the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> should i keep it to make the page and the logo responsive ? and what is the role of class="logo" ?

Comment: Yeah, you can keep the meta tag. The logo class was just to make the logo a bit smaller and keep it at the center using `margin: auto`. You can change the value of the `width` attribute to whatever width you like.